# How to get the Token from Django server and use it in subsequent API request using Volley

Tags: authentication, android-volley

I am using `Django` `Rest Api` as a backend for my android app.I need to send username and password to server to get the `Token`.This received token I need to send in header for all further Api request.I am using [volley](/questions/tagged/volley) in android for making Networking calls.How to send `Username` and `Password` to get the Token ?
How to send that Token in Volley Header ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make a request with the username and password to retrieve the authentication token:

```
JSONObject postparams = new JSONObject();
postparams.put("username","the_username")
postparams.put("password","the_password")

JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
        "/url/to/obtain/token/end/point", postparams,
        new Response.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                /** Retrieve the token from the response **/
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            }
        });
```

Once you have the token, you pass it in the `Authorization` HTTP header in all subsequent API requests:

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
        "/url/to/some/api/end/point", null,
        new Response.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
              //Success Callback
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            }
        })

{

    /** Pass the token in the Authorization header **/
    @Override
    public Map<string, string=""> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        HashMap<string, string=""> headers = new HashMap<string, string="">();
        headers.put("Authorization", "Token 9944b09199c62bcf9418ad846dd0e4bbdfc6ee4b");
        return headers;
    }
};
```